# Combining two lists one after another

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine lists to produce a result like this:
[a, 1, b, 2, c, 3] but i can't get it to work. Can u tell me what's wrong/show me how to do it?

```
def newList(a, b):
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(zip(a, b))
    return tmp

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]

print(newList(a, b))
```

I get only zip object at 0x0449FE18 as a result.

Comment: You need to convert it to a list in the end.

Comment: `import operator; print list(reduce(operator.concat,zip(a,b)))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to flatten the sequence produced by `zip`. The easiest way to do that is using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2,3])))
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]
```

The class method `from_iterable` takes the iterable-of-iterables like `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ...]`, and turns it into a single iterable by extracting the elements from the subiterables one at a time, from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [x for y in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'],[1, 2, 3]) for x in y]
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

without imports

b = [1, 2]

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

```
result = [item for a in map(None, a, b) for item in a][:-1]
```

['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c']

***important array "b" has one element less than  array "a"***

.

**if has the same length**

```
result = [item for a in map(None, a, b) for item in a]
```

['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `zip`. Assuming both lists have the same amount of elements (as is in your question) you can do something as simple as

```
newList = list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    newList.append(a[i])
    newList.append(b[i])
print(newList)
```

if the lists are not the same size then you need to ask yourself some questions about ordering but you can do it as simple as

```
newList = list()
biggestList = len(a) if len(a) > len(b) else len(b)
for i in range(biggestList):
    if a[i]:
        newList.append(a[i])
    if b[i]:
        newList.append(b[i])
print(newList)
```

you can play around with this logic depending on what your criteria are for the list sizes and how to handle the order.